# How to change camera view?

Tags: camera

When I switch to camera view, the focus is on the middle of an object, and not the whole scene. Already tried:

- to change focal length of the camera
- change clipping settings
- and the view is not locked

My file: https://workupload.com/file/cATrTgzcbYU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment your camera is inside the ground so you won't see anything through it:

[image]

You need to move it, a convenient way to move a camera is to lock the camera to view, you'll be able to move in camera view as you move in your 3D scene (btw I prefer to enable the *Preferences > Navigation > Orbit Around Selection*, when you are in camera view it also makes things easier):

[image]

Also you need to increase the camera *Clip End* value, otherwise some parts will be invisible:

[image]